# Automatically remove spaces when joining two lines into the one

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button at the end of a current line:

```
            []<- a currsor is here
        )
```

, a text on a next line obviously jumps to the current line and it becomes something like this:

```
            []                )
```

So we have a bunch of spaces in the joined text (between square brackets and paranthesis in the example above), so we have to delete them manually.

In the "big" Visual Studio (maybe because of ReSharper) all those spaces get deleted automatically and immediately, with a single <kbd>Delete</kbd> stroke, we  have what we wanted to do:

```
            [])
```

How can we remove those spaces with Visual Studio Code automatically? Is there a setting for this?

Comment: try Keyboard:  CTRL + K, CTRL + \ or
Menu:  Edit -> Advanced -> Delete Horizontal White Space
C

Comment: @PDKPavanKumar thank you. For some reason, I don't have the `Advanced` item in the `Edit` menu and neither of those shortcuts work for me. Anyway, I'm looking for a way to do it automatically without any additional keystrokes every time.

Comment: Look at the `Join Lines` command - it is as close as you will get.  The first comment was about "visual Studio", not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @Mark `Join Lines` seems to be a keyboard shortcut. If so, then it's not much of a help. As I explained in my question\comment, I'm looking for a way to do it automatically.

Comment: That is why I said it is as close as you will get.

Comment: @Mark I believe it's a pretty simple 'refactoring'. So if it has not been implemented in VSCode itself yet, there could be an extension performing this task, maybe as a part of its feature set.

Comment: I don't see an extension anymore - there is a deprecated one you could try.  But you would have to trigger it with some command anyway, so you might as well join lines command - which you would have to give a keybinding.

Comment: @Mark Does VSCode API for extensions provide a way to do it automatically without the need for creating a specific command for it?

Comment: I would think an extension could do it.  So upon a `delete` detect if it included a newline, if so also delete any leading whitespace on the "next" line.

Comment: @Mark I'm confused, then. You wrote `But you would have to trigger it with some command anyway` first and `I would think an extension could do it.` after that. Not sure which one is correct.

Comment: An existing extension is very unlikely to be triggered by pressing a `delete` key, it would have a keybinding to trigger a join lines command.  But you could write your own that would listen for `delete`'s and ultimately do what you want.

Comment: @Mark Now I see, thank you! Writing a custom extension is exactly why I've been asking for those details.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, while making a macro to do what you wanted, I see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> does exactly what you want when at the end of a line.

If you wanted to only use the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key and nothing else, you will need an extension of some kind.  A macro could do the job but it sounds like you want the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to work differently within a line of code than from at the very end.  Something a macro would not be able to distinguish.  An extension could do that.

But I suggest just use the simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! This information could be used as a fallback solution if nothing else would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure there is **not** a command or setting like this built in to VSCode.

- It is always difficult to prove a negative.  I looked at all the keys and settings with "delete" and "backspace" (as you probably did too) and came up empty.  I've also made a number of excursions into the source and github issues for various reasons, and have a sense for the level of sophistication of what is implemented in VSCode; this is beyond what VSCode tends to have.

However, there is an extension called [Hungry Delete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jasonlhy.hungry-delete) that does something similar, although not quite what you've asked for.  I suggest trying to modify it; I doubt it would be difficult.  Whatever logic you come up with can be bound to <kbd>Delete</kbd>, supplanting the usual behavior.

Of course, if you haven't written an extension before, start with the (quick) [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) first.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the reference links! I'll check them out!